# Supplying another function to sum() as a start parameter

Tags: python, function, sum

I have seen the below function in a tutorial about packaging.

My doubt is in `sum()` which takes `Counter()` as the *start* parameter. What would happen in this case?

```py
# Import needed functionality
from collections import Counter

def sum_counters(counters):
  # Sum the inputted counters
  return sum(counters, Counter())
```

I tried replicating using the below code

```py
a=[2,3,3,4,5,5,6]
sum(a,len())
```

Result:

```
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

I'm unable to replicate it with `Counter()` (due to an error in pip while downloading collections package), nor am i able to find any documentation that mentions about giving functions as the *start* parameters.

Could anyone throw some light on this. Thanks

Comment: collections is stdlib, don't involve pip here..

Comment: You aren't passing a function to `sum`, you are passing the *result* of a function call.

Comment: well, the result of a *call* at least :) some of the neat things that Python does, pose a bit of a challenge for standard programming terminology.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish by using `len()` as the start parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Counter()` provides an empty instance of `Counter`; `len` cannot be called with no arguments.

`sum(counters, Counter())` is roughly equivalent to

```
result = Counter()
for x in counters:
    result = result + x
```

You can do this because addition is defined for instance of `Counter`.

For the example you are trying, you want as a starting value is the length of an empty list:

```
sum(a, len([]))
```

Since `len([]) == 0`, it's the same as `sum(a, 0)` or just `sum(a)`.

Comment: Given that I'm not keeping a reference to the starting value, the distinction isn't terribly important for the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: @wim Those are implementation details, they don't affect the semantics of the program. He said it's *roughly* equivalent, and this is useful for explaining the result of the call.

Comment: @Barmar To be fair, I added "roughly" in response to his comment; I've also now replaced the use of `+=`.

Answer (score 2):

> My doubt is in the sum() which takes Counter() as the start parameter. What would happen in this case ?

Just as in any other case, it takes the initial `Counter()` and adds the first element of `counters` to it, then it adds the next one to that result, and so on. This is the same as if you had used the `+` symbol between all of the `Counter` instances explicitly. To understand what *that* does, [see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

> TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Well, yes, like it says; `len` needs to know what to get the length *of*. I don't understand what you want this `sum` call to *do*.

> nor am i able to find any documentation that mentions about giving functions as the start parameters.

`collections.Counter` *isn't* a function; it's a *class*. However, `len(x)` isn't a function either; it's the *result of calling* that function. (Similarly, the *result of calling* the `collections.Counter` class is a `collections.Counter` *instance*.) Anyway, it doesn't matter where the `start` parameter comes from; what matters is the *value* it has. For example:

```
a=[2,3,3,4,5,5,6]
sum(a,len(a))
```

`a` has 7 items in it, so `len(a)` is equal to `7`, and the result is the same as writing `sum(a, 7)` directly. That is `7 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 6` = `35`.